# Vue async event listener in template syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a child component, that dispatches an event to the parent and goes into a loading state until the parent component has resolved that event.

**It is possible** to use async methods as a callback for events in the template like so:

**Parent Template:**

```
<some-child
  @refresh="done => myAsyncCallback(done)"
>
```

**Parent Component:**

```
methods: {
  async myAsyncCallback(done) {
     await someVuexAction()
     done() // notify the child the call is done
  }
}
```

**Child Component**

```
// Set component state to loading and change back once finished
this.loading = true
this.$emit('refresh', done => {this.loading = false}
```

Now that is a lot of boilerplate, I'd rather just put that `async myAsyncCallback` method of the parent right into my template as an anonymous function.

**I imagine something like that:**

```
<some-child
  @refresh="async done => await someVuexAction() && done()"
>
```

Unfortunately, this code gives me an `Syntax Error: Unexpected token, expected "," (1:421)`

Any suggestions?

Comment: `@refresh="done => someVuexAction().then(done)"` ?

Comment: `@refresh="(async (done) => {await someVuexAction(); done()})"` would probably work too. But why this? Why not just pass `someVuexAction` as prop and have this boilerplate be handled by the child alone?

Comment: @acdcjunior I felt like it makes more sense when the child delegates to the parent rather than the other way around but you're right, that version would probably be even easier.